# django finding model (profile) empty fields

Tags: django

i have user and profile models
i want to find which fields of profile are empty for each user.

something like
empty_field_users=User.objects.filter(profile__fields='')

for instance

if my profile has fields like

name
logo
description

and user did not fill out something to description and saved his profile.
i want to get this user in empty_field_users

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see what you have specified should work fine, assuming 'description' is a non-null field with a default empty string value.

```
no_description = User.objects.filter(profile__description='')
```

If it ***is*** a null field, you can do it like this:

```
no_description = User.objects.filter(profile__description__isnull=True)
```

Docs [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).